# Blueimp jquery file upload alternative file names cause the preview missing

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

The client can preview before uploading but cannot see after uploding as the local language file name.

[image]
So I want to rename the filename before upload the image for it can preview before and after uploading.

reference the https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API

```
How to provide alternative file names:
The name property of File objects is read only, but an alternative name can be provided as uploadName property for each individual file:

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        var count = data.files.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            data.files[i].uploadName =
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + '_' + data.files[i].name;
        }
        data.submit();
    }
});
```

---

When I use above js function the preview is good function when the image add and submit to server immediately~

But when I delete

```
data.submit();
```

as I want client to decide if upload or not before uploading.

the preview image  function  is missing! 
and cannot upload any file.

Does any code can rename for the unicode filename (as the local language encoing filename cannot show on the preview function when it uploaded) before submit to the server?

Answer (score 0):

jquery.fileupload.js
....

```
  } else {
                $.each(options.files, function (index, file) {
                    // This check allows the tests to run with
                    // dummy objects:
                    if (that._isInstanceOf('File', file) ||
                            that._isInstanceOf('Blob', file)) {
                        formData.append(
                            ($.type(options.paramName) === 'array' &&
                                options.paramName[index]) || paramName,
                            file,
                            file.uploadName || file.name
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

change the last

```
file.uploadName || file.name
```

to

```
encodeURI(file.uploadName || file.name)
```

then can see the write decode in the back
fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileDetail.getFileName(), "UTF-8");